# Why is absolute convergence required?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, density-function

Definitions try to precisely formalize intuitive ideas. For example, the concept of mathematical expectation attempts to rigorously formalize the idea of quantifying the average outcome of a random variable, considering all possible values and their respective probabilities. So, given a random variable of the continuous type $X$ with probability density function $f$, in the definition of mathematical expectation of $X$ it is required that
$$\int_{-a}^{a} |x|f(x) dx$$
converges if $a \rightarrow +\infty$. What reason is there for this requirement?

Comment: If that’s not true, the law of large numbers can fail. (And will fail, in the strong form, if I recall correctly.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Could you specify please? I don't know the law of large numbers. :(

Comment: It says that the average value of an independent random sample from a distribution converges to the expected value of the distribution as the sample size gets large. Look it up on Wikipedia for more information.

Comment: You can work without that requirement, but it can be tricky (just as conditionally convergent series can be hard to work with).  The usual problematic example involves the Cauchy Distribution and is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)

Comment: Thank you so much!! :)